# .on is not a function

Tags: node.js, electron, udp

From electron I pass node.js modules with the contextBridge to the interface like this:

```
  const udp = require('dgram');

  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
      udp: udp,
    }
  )
```

Then for example in the web console I can do:

```
  var udp = window.electron.udp

  var client = udp.createSocket('udp4');
```

Most of the methods on `client` work.

**But when I try to attach event handlers I this error:**

```
client.on('message',function(msg,info){
  console.log('Data received from server : ' + msg.toString());
});

=> VM542:1 Uncaught TypeError: client.on is not a function
```

**I don't understand why in the web console I can't use the on-methods?**
How should I listen to events there? Or could this error be related to Jquery?

Thank you

I know that I could set: `contextIsolation: false` but then I got other errors.

`client => {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, type: "udp4", Symbol(kCapture): false, …}`

Comment: [related](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21437)? + [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27120)